# Telegram to send playable video

Tags: video, telegram, telegram-bot, send

What is the trick to send playable video to telegram?

I can see two types of videos in telegram,

- One has a "Play Video" option that allows people [Play Video Without Downloading on Telegram](http://www.themicrople.com/news/play-video-without-downloading-telegram/)
- The other type does not have such option but only provide "Download" option

What's the trick to get the first result?

Notes,

- I know telegram clients support mp4 videos, and I've seen playable videos in telegram that's really huge, both in resolution and in size
- I'm using [node-telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/release/doc/api.md#telegrambotsendvideochatid-video-options-fileoptions--promise) to send videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not playable video is a video sent as a document without compression. You can also sent photos without compression and more.
Playable video is a video or animation object.

Answer is you should use sendVideo, not sendDocument method. Also the video should be MP4 (or animation in gif/webm), otherwise telegram can still send it as a document

Comment: If you had checked the url I mentioned in my OP, you'd had known I am using `telegramBot.sendVideo`